# Install PHP tidy extension into XAMPP in Windows

Tags: php, xampp, tidy

I want to add PHP Tidy to my XAMPP installation on Windows. However, I don't really know where to start and am not familiar with the command line. I found the php.ini file and uncommented the lines where it spoke about Tidy. However, this produced:

```
Warning: PARSERHTML::_load_html(): Unable to load Tidy configuration file at 
'/usr/local/lib/php/default.tcfg'. in 
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Entwicklung\root\phitCMS\features\phpdocx\classes\DOMPDF_lib.php on line 
2660

Warning: tidy_parse_string(): Unable to load Tidy configuration file at 
'/usr/local/lib/php/default.tcfg'. in 
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\Entwicklung\root\phitCMS\features\phpdocx\classes\DOMPDF_lib.php on 
line 2688
```

Further, I read on Stackoverflow but only found solutions regarding Mac OSX and something called "Homebrew".

Also I wonder: What will happen if I install Tidy locally and upload my website online? Then Tidy will eventually not be there and my website does not work properly?

Comment: update your tidy extension_dir in `php.ini` to use windows path please

Comment: "_and my website does not work properly?_" Exactly

Comment: Thank you @KenLee - is the path itself correct though? So only forward slashes instead of back slashes?

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/php/` is a Linux path. So no, the path is not correct on Windows

Comment: @brombeer I didn't change anything - that's how my XAMPP came. Is that a mistake and shall I re-install XAMPP?

Comment: Not sure if this is a XAMPP related error or rather a phitCMS/phpdocx/DOMPDF_lib.php one.

Comment: @brombeer Can you give me a tip on how to proceed debugging? I'm a bit lost..